# Log in Program in PHP not working

Tags: php

As part of my project i created a log in program. i already have a create account page from which the data is going in to the database tables successfully. But my log in program is not working. Below is my code.

```
 <?php


 $db  = mysql_connect('localhost','root','','childrenparty');


 if(!$db){die('could not connect:'.mysql_error());}

echo'connected successfully';


if (isset($_POST['loginbtn'])) {

$username = $_POST['txtusername'];
$password = $_POST['txtpassword'];

 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
 $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientinfo WHERE Username ='".$username."'' AND 
 Password='".$password."' LIMIT 1";
 $result = mysql_query($sql); 
 echo $sql;

 if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
   {
  echo "<script> alert('Successfully Logged In')</script>";
  echo "<script> location.href = 'home.php' </script>";
  exit();
  }
   else  {
  echo "<script> alert('Invalid Username and/or Password')</script>";
  exit();
  }
  }

  mysql_close($db);




 ?>
```

so the problem is it always shows invalid username and password when i try to sign in. please help

Comment: Please 1) show your register code 2) Stop using mysql_* functions 3) After fixing 2, use prepared statements.

Comment: probably your password or your username is injecting some sql code in your outdated mysql api

Comment: and please dont save the password in plain text in your db

Comment: in your else statement please add "echo mysql_error()"; to track any query error...

Comment: in addition to all previous comments, add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of page and get rid of un extra `'` in `WHERE Username =' ".$username." ' ' `

Comment: Mysql_* is deprecated you should really look into using mysqli_ or PDO.

Comment: Also you should use password_hash and password_verify instead of storing plain passwords to your database

Comment: thanx guys for the replys...i have posted the answer below..it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have a error in sql query, an extra `'`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clientinfo WHERE Username ='" . $username . "' AND
 Password='" . $password . "' LIMIT 1";
```

But there are **more dangerous** problems in this code:

1. mysql_* are deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7, so you'd better use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) functions and prepared statements.
2. Password is stored unencrypted and this is a huge vulnerability

I'll add an example with prepared statements, to prevent SQL Injection:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'childrenparty');

if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: (' . $db->connect_errno . ') ' . $db->connect_error;
}else{
    echo 'Connected successfully';
}

if (isset($_POST['loginbtn'])) {

    $username = $_POST['txtusername'];
    $password = $_POST['txtpassword'];

    $username = $db->escape_string($username);
    $password = $db->escape_string($password);

    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM clientinfo WHERE Username=? AND Password=? LIMIT 1');
    $query->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    $query->execute();

    $result = $query->get_result()->fetch_row();

    if (null !== $result) {
        echo "<script> alert('Successfully Logged In')</script>";
        echo "<script> location.href = 'home.php' </script>";
        exit();
    }

    echo "<script> alert('Invalid Username and/or Password')</script>";
    exit();
}

$db->close();
```

Comment: Yes, definitely. I'll add an example, to show how to avoid SQL Injection here

Comment: thanx man..but it worked with a different code with a bit of change...i have added it below for future use..

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have made some changes to your code. This should definetly work. If not the problem is withing the $_POST variable names that you have set. Also double check the Sql query to check if they are the same as the database names. I assume you are just learning to code so its fine but mysql is deprecated now , so try to use mysqli functions.

For further reference check out http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

```
 if (isset($_POST['loginbtn'])) {

    $username = $_POST['txtusername'];
    $password = $_POST['txtpassword'];

     $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
     $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientinfo WHERE Username = '$username' AND 
     Password = '$password' LIMIT 1";
     $result = mysql_query($sql); 

     if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
       {
      echo "<script> alert('Successfully Logged In')</script>";
      echo "<script> location.href = 'home.php' </script>";
      }
       else  {
      echo "<script> alert('Invalid Username and/or Password')</script>";
      }
      }
```

Comment: thanx for the reply man... it worked when i added a count variable...i will share it with you...

Answer (score -1):

```
     <?php


$db  = mysql_connect('localhost','root','','childrenparty');


  if(!$db){die('could not connect:'.mysql_error());}

    echo'connected successfully';


 if (isset($_POST['loginbtn'])) {

 $username = $_POST['txtusername'];
 $password = $_POST['txtpassword'];

  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
  $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientinfo WHERE Username ='$username' AND 
   Password='$password'";
 mysql_select_db('childrenparty');
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
 $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

 if($count == 1) {
 echo "<script> alert('You Have Successfully Logged In')</script>";
 echo "<script> location.href = 'home.php' </script>";
exit();
} else {
 echo "<script> alert('Invalid Username and/or Password')</script>";
 }
 }

  mysql_close($db);




 ?>
```

this one worked.thanks guys for the reply.